# UIAutomator pressing Select All after textselection to clear text with spaces

Tags: automated-tests, android, android-uiautomator

I have got a text like "ABC XYZ"

```
//Below Code selects ABC and clears it and enter 123 , resulting in "123 XYZ"

editText.setText("123");
```

Is there a way I can select the entire string even if it has spaces in it.

Answer (score 3):

You can use below workaround :

```
String text = editText.getText();
editText.clickBottomRight();
for (int i=0;i<text.length();i++) {
    UiDevice.getInstance().pressDelete();
}
editText.setText("123");
```

Answer (score 0):

Can't you try this instead, This will clear the editText box value and then set it.

editText.clearText();

editText.setText("123");

Comment: Did try this but that doesnt work. Also setText internally performs clearText as per the api doc.

Answer (score -1):

This is the workaround I'm using:

```
editText.longClick();
```

pause for 50 ms:

```
//UiObject selectAll = new UiObject(new UiSelector().descriptionContains("Select all"));
selectAll.click();
```

pause for 250 ms:

```
//UiDevice dev = getInstance();
dev.pressKeyCode(KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DEL, 0);
```

You might want to play with pause.